# advanced if excel formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to write an excel formula that calculates cell x divided by cell y, but if the resulting value is between 0 and -.3 return a value of 0, but if less than.-.3 then return the inverse square of cell x divided by cell y. Can you please help as I am at my wits end. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried it? Where did you stuck?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that B1 is cell X and B2 is cell Y, this should work:

`=IF(AND((B1/B2)>=-0.3,(B1/B2)<=0),0,IF((B1/B2)<-0.3,1/((B1/B2)^2),(B1/B2)))`